# Not satisfied with outcome of continuity proof

Tags: proof-verification, continuity

For $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}: f(x) = x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, show that $f$ is continuous at all $x\neq 0$. I was advised to complete the proof like so:

> \begin{align*}
> \text{We will show $f$ is continuous at all $c \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.}\\
> \forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta > 0 \mid \forall x: \left|x-c\right|<\delta \Longrightarrow \left|f(x)-f(c)\right|<\epsilon\\
> \Longrightarrow \left|x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-c\sin\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)\right| < \epsilon\\
> \iff \left|x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-c\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+c\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-c\sin\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)\right|<\epsilon\\
> \iff \left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(x-c\right)+c\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)\right)\right|<\epsilon\\
> \text{By the Triangle Inequality, we have}\\
> \iff \leq \left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(x-c\right)\right|+ \left|c\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)\right)\right|<\epsilon\\
> \iff \left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|\left|x-c\right| + \left|c\right|\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)\right|<\epsilon\\
> \text{We know that $\sin{x}$ is bounded above by $1$, and $\left|x-c\right|$ is bounded above by $\delta$. Hence we have}\\
> \iff < \delta + \left|c\right| < \epsilon\\
> \text{Pick $\delta:=1$. Then we have}\\
> \Longrightarrow 1 + \left|c\right| < \epsilon\\
> \Longrightarrow 0< \epsilon - \left|c\right| - 1
> \end{align*}
>   Hence, for $\delta:=\min\left\{1, \left|\epsilon-|c|-1\right|\right\}$, we have $|x-c|<\delta \Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$. Because $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrarily chosen, it follows that $f$ is continuous at all $c \neq 0$.

Would this proof work? Can I assume that $\left|\epsilon-|c|-1\right|$ can be turned into an absolute value? Somehow this proof does not sit right with me.

Comment: No, it does not work: what if $\epsilon<1$?

Comment: How do you get $\left|x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-c\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+c\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-c\sin\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)\right|<\epsilon?$ It seems like you're saying $c\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-c\sin\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)=0$

Comment: I just admire the way your equation are displayed. new fashion

Comment: If $x\ne 0,$ both $x$ and $\sin(1/x)$ are continuous.  Why not just say that the product of continuous functions is continuous?

Comment: @saulspatz No, I'm adding and subtracting $c\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$ in the same step. It's the same as $\left|x^2-4\right| = \left| x^2 - 2x + 2x - 4 \right|$

Comment: @saulspatz I would rather like to see how I can fix this proof.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I thought so. How may I fix it?